# In R, is there a way to handle NA in an integer column of a data.frame so that NA values are not included when subsetting?

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

I have a data.frame like this:

```
(t=structure(list(count = c(NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = "count", row.names = c(NA,-9L), class = "data.frame"))
  count
1    NA
2     2
3    NA
4    NA
5    NA
6     8
7    NA
8    NA
9    NA
```

It is great that R has the NA value but sometimes it bites me. I often forget about it and try to do subsetting like this

```
> t[t$count>=1,]
[1] NA  2 NA NA NA  8 NA NA NA
```

And the output includes all NA rows. (which I don't like)

After an hour of bug searching  I change the code to this and that is what I want (**imagine large dataframe** a lots of non-NA resuls and only few "well-hidden" NAs):

```
> t[t$count>=1&!is.na(t$count),]
[1] 2 8
```

1.
Is there a feature of the "as.integer" function so that I could do something like this:

> t[as.integer.EXCLUDE.NA(t$count)>=1,]

I would want to use such feature in other as.xxxx functions as well. Basically force R to stop think like a statistician and treat NA differently (e.g., like NULL (I am not sure NULL would solve my issue) (this did not work: t$count[3]<-NULL for some reason)

2.
or how would I run

```
transform(t, replace all NAs from count columns with 0)
```

or even better

```
transform(t, replace all NA from all numeric columns with 0 in t)
```

3.
any generic comments on making R forget about NAs are welcomed?

Comment: I see the value of NAs, but there are data sets where NAs are not welcomed.

Comment: But how do you want to handle them --  Drop each NA?  Drop each row where there are any NAs?  Impute them?  It's a substantive decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not like the choices that were made at the time of designing how "[" handles NA values either. The approach I take when I want to extract values using a logical test is to wrap the logical expression in `which`. This converts the result to a set of numbers and indexing succeeds without dragging along the unwanted NA's:

```
> t[ which(t$count >= 1), ]
[1] 2 8
# Or if you still want a dataframe result
> t[ which(t$count >= 1), , drop=FALSE]
  count
2     2
6     8
```

I also use `subset` since it handles NA's in the same manner as `which(logical)`. The one gotcha is when `which` is used with a "-" sign to retrieve the complement set. If there are no elements in the set satisfying the logical-condition, there will also be no elements in the `-which(logical)`-form. So I just do not use the `-which` combo:

```
> t[ -which(t$count < 1), , drop=FALSE]
[1] count
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> t[ which(t$count < 1), , drop=FALSE]
[1] count
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: I used subset() and then switched to [] since it was faster. But your answers makes a great point to go back to subset() in some cases

Answer (score 7):

In [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) it works as you'd like it to w.r.t. `NA`, if I understand correctly. Also, you don't need to use `$` and it doesn't mind if you forget the comma, either.

```
dt = as.data.table(t)
t[count>=1]   # NA's are treated as FALSE
```

The list of differences between `data.table` and `data.frame` is in FAQ 2.17 [here](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf).

If you're thinking all these differences break compatibility, they don't. You can still pass a `data.table` to any package and when those packages use standard R syntax on the `data.table`, it still works.

Since you said *large* `data.frame`, `data.table` may be worth a look anyway.

These are the 3 points from FAQ 2.17 (where `DT` means `data.table` and `DF` means `data.frame`) :

- `DT[NA]` returns 1 row of `NA`, but `DF[NA]` returns a copy of the whole of `DF`
  containing `NA` throughout. The symbol `NA` is type logical in R, and is
  therefore recycled by `[.data.frame`. Intention was probably
  `DF[NA_integer_]`. `[.data.table` does this automatically for
  convenience.
- `DT[c(TRUE,NA,FALSE)]` treats the `NA` as `FALSE`, but
  `DF[c(TRUE,NA,FALSE),]` returns an `NA` row for each `NA`
- `DT[ColA==ColB]` is
  simpler than `DF[!is.na(ColA) & !is.na(ColB) & ColA==ColB,]`

Comment: Thx. Yet another impulse to look into data.table

Answer (score 3):

Easy enough to do (2) on the list (replace all NAs):

```
t$count[is.na(t$count)] <- something.else
```

The question is, of course, what do you put in for `something.else`.  NAs exist to solve a problem.  If you want to blanket ban them from your use of R, you'll need to figure out what you want to do with missing observations other than treat them as missing.

The beauty of NA is it generally propagates through, indicating to you at the end of your analysis that somewhere in there you had some missingness which you'd better go think hard about.  There's no substitute for thinking hard about missingness.

Comment: +1 for your explanation, and for being able to see beauty in NAs :)

Comment: If the first step on the path to enlightenment is being glad of the existence of error messages, and the second step is seeing the beauty in NAs, what's the third step?